# add items to a list from class variable

Tags: java, java-8

I have created a class named Test with (name and surname variables) plus getter and setter, then I made a List with Test type. I use set method to set variables value and then I try to add `klass.setName(nminput)` and `klass.setSurname(surnminput);` to the List but only one value being added even with loops. Is there anyway to add item to a List from class variable?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Test klass = new Test("name", "surname");
List < Test > list = new ArrayList < > ();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String nminput = input.next();
    String surnminput = input.next();
    klass.setName(nminput);
    klass.setSurname(surnminput);
    list.add(klass);
    i++;
}
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: You seem to be adding the same `Test` instance to your list, multiple times. Perhaps you meant to add multiple `Test` instances instead.

Comment: Also you're incrementing `i` twice each turn through your loop.

Comment: Just a question : it is not possible to change exact same object value and added it to the List?

Comment: That is what you're doing: changing the same object and adding it repeatedly to the list. So you end up with multiple references to the same object in your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the value for the same Test object (it's called Klass) again and again you want to create multiple Test objects inside you're loop.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    String nminput = input.next();
    String surnminput = input.next();
    Test klass = new Test(nminput, surnminput);
    list.add(klass);
    i++;
}
    System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Just a question : it is not possible to change exact same object value and added it to the List?

Comment: No because of how objects work in java. In Java when you store a object somewhere, for example in a list, you only store a reference to it. Only the keyword `new` creates a new object which can have different values.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the porblem